# What is the meaning of the construct "Willst du was trinken?"

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality, grammar-identification, question

I'm really new to learning Deutsch. I'm trying to understand the grammatical logic so to speak behind the "construct"

> Willst du was trinken?

1. Aren't only closed questions supposed to have the verb in the beginning? Why is *willst* in the beginning here?
2. What is the reason behind *was* here?
3. Is it correct to say or perhaps what is the difference between that and *Welche Getränke möchten Sie?*

Comment: Sorry, I don't see what can be unclear here... In a question the verb is is usually in the first position... Willst = 2. person singular. Why? Because of "du" that is the subject... And the question IS closed as it asks for IF the other person wants to drink something, not WHAT they want to drink. The correct answer would be: "Ja bitte" or "Nein Danke". And "...möchten Sie" is the more formal approach... that would be: "Wollen Sie (et)was trinken?" in the first way of asking...

Comment: Torst Link, you miss the entire point of the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Willst du was trinken?
> *Do you want something to drink?*

The sentence you gave is in fact a [yes-no question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes%E2%80%93no_question) (I assume that is what you mean by *closed question*). That is the reason why the verb is in first position.

In the given case, *was* is not a question word (interrogative pronoun) but an indefinite pronoun with the same meaning as *etwas*. Note that *wer*, usually an interrogative pronoun, has a similar indefinite use, at least in spoken German:

> Hat wer (=jemand) für mich angerufen?
> *Did someone try to call me?*

As opposed to the given sentence,

> Welche Getränke möchten Sie?
> *Which drinks would you like?*

is of course a wh-question with the verb in second position and a wh-word in first position.

Comment: To reduce confusion for a language learner, I'd suggest writing "Hat wer ( = irgendwer)" instead of "=jemand"

Comment: I did miss the meaning of the question "Do you want something to drink" not "What do you want to drink". But I had no idea about the 'was' job in that sentence. That indeed made the whole sentence clear for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Arsak To me, *irgend-* introduces extra emphasis. Therefore, *jemand* is a better paraphrase for *wer* than *irgendwer*. The latter would go with *irgendjemand*. (Historically, *wer* belongs to *etwer* just as *was* belongs to *etwas*.)

Comment: @DavidVogt Oh, *etwer* was new to me. Thank you for mentioning!

Comment: Would it be correct to write it "Willst du 'was trinken?". Or does German not do the apostrophes like on english?

Comment: @BruceWayne *Was* is not considered to be derived from *etwas*. Using an interrogative pronoun as an indefinite pronoun is nothing unusual. In fact, indefinite *was* has its own dictionary [entry](https://www.dwds.de/wb/was#2); for others, the indefinite use is listed under the entry of the interrogative, e.g. [wo](https://www.dwds.de/wb/wo#d-1-1-3). (Actually, DWDS lists the indefinite use of *was* under the entry for the interrogative pronoun as well: [was](https://www.dwds.de/wb/was#d-1-3).)

Comment: Despite being a yes-no-question, a typical answer will often supply a proposal as in *Ja, ein Mineralwasser wäre nett*.